# Azure AD v2.0: using powershell to get info

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to use powershell to get info about my default ad. The first thing I do is sign on using my global admin account through the Connect-AzureAD cmdlet:

```
Connect-AzureAD
```

After running this command, I get something that looks like this:

```
Account               Environment TenantId                             TenantDomain
-------               ----------- --------                             ------------
xxxyyyxcxx@hotmail.com AzureCloud  zzz-xxxx-yyyyyyy
```

Now, whenever I try to run any command, I get an error saying that I'm not authorized to do that. For instance, If try to get all the groups, I get the following:

```
Get-AzureADGroup : Error occurred while executing GetGroups
Code: Authentication_Unauthorized
Message: User was not found
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is: the cmdlet `Get-AzureADGroup` has no tenant specified, so the connection was established to a domain, where user has no admin privileges.
To ensure connection to expected AAD domain, the tenant ID must specified in call to Connect-AzureAD cmdlet. You could use the following cmdlet to login your tenant ID.

```
Connect-Azuread -TenantID <your tenantid>
```

You could get your users's tenantID with `Get-AzureRmSubscription`.

More information please refer to this [blog](http://winmike.blogspot.sg/2017/02/azure-active-directory-connect-aad-for.html).